# Node.js prototypal inheritance with require

Tags: javascript, inheritance, node.js, prototype-programming

I have a problem with inheritance of two functions in node.js when i use require functions.

Here is my case:

```
function administrators () {
    this.user = 'bob';
}
administrators.prototype.print_user = function () {
    console.log(this.user);
}

/*******/


function helper() {}

helper.prototype = new administrators();

helper.prototype.change_administrator = function() {
    this.user = 'john';

}

var h = new helper();

h.print_user();
h.change_administrator();
h.print_user();
```

As you can see here I have two functions:

- `administrations` just has user variable and `print_user` function.
- `helpers` inherits everything from `administrators` and then we add `change_administrator` which changes `this.use` declared in `administrators()`.

Here is the question:

I want to have this functions (`administrators` and `helper`) in separated files, for example: `administrators.js` and `helper.js`.

Then I want to include these two files in `index.js` with `require`, and inherit `administrators` variables and functions to helper like I did in the example above.

P.S. I was looking for similar questions but there is nothing about that kind of inheritance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to require administrators from within the helpers.js file.

administrators.js

```
function administrators () {
    this.user = 'bob';
}
administrators.prototype.print_user = function () {
    console.log(this.user);
}

module.exports = administrators;
```

helpers.js

```
var administrators = require('./administrators');

function helper() {}

helper.prototype = new administrators();

helper.prototype.change_administrator = function() {
    this.user = 'john';
};

module.exports = helper;
```

index.js

```
var helper = require('./helpers');

var h = new helper();

h.print_user();
h.change_administrator();
h.print_user();
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have to manually extend them in the class that did the requiring.

Extend here meaning "copy the methods and properties from one object to the other"

alternately have helpers require administrator directly